# How to Unit test a controller in Play/Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I'm having trouble when trying to test a controller that sends a POST request to the API. I've tried different ways of testing it but I keep on getting the same "400" response. I believe the format of the json val is correct because I've tested it using Swagger and it works fine. Can anybody help me to understand what I'm missing here. Many thanks.

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""[{"id":"1","address":"my address"}]""")
val mockAddressFinder = mock(classOf[AddressFinder])

"Example test" should {
  "should be valid" in {
   val controller = new Match(mockAddressFinder)
   val results = controller.match.apply(FakeRequest(
    POST,
      "test/test",
      FakeHeaders(Seq("Content-type"->("application/json"))),
    json
   ))
   results.onComplete {
    case Success(_) => results.map(s => println("hello" + s.header.status))
    case _=> println("did not work")
  }
}
```

Comment: Which classes are you extending?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this. This is working on me.

```
   val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(POST, "/someUrl", FakeHeaders(), AnyContentAsJson(Json.parse("""[{"id":"1","address":"my address"}]""")))
   val futureResult: Future[Result] = route(application, fakeRequest).get
   val resultJson: JsValue = contentAsJson(futureResult)(Timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
   resultJson.toString mustBe """{"status":"success"}"""
```

Comment: What is the `application` configuration you are using? Are you extending some class? Please give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Is match a method in the controller?

I think you should be doing

```
controller.match()(FakeRequest....)
```

`controller.match()` should return an `Action`, that is a function from a request to a result. To this function, you should pass your fake request.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.